# How to change default pilot?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

What happened to me yesterday:

1. I made a rocket
2. Put Bob in it
3. Start
4. Crash
5. Revert to vehicle assembly
6. Fix crash reason
7. Start

And then I realized Bob wasn't there, Jeb was piloting my ship! How can I stop that? How can I prevent Jeb from pushing his butt into my rocket if I haven't invited him? If I chose a pilot for specific ship, I want my choice to be kinda persistent (until **I** change it), so how can I achieve that?

Comment: Why on kerbin would one want anyone *but* Jebediah piloting a ship?

Comment: @KendallFrey There is this little something called "pilot's reputation" now, and whilst I have no idea how exactly it works, I don't want to loose it all if I'll kill Jeb and science + contract gains will prevent me from reverting flight.

Comment: Jeb never dies, he merely gets "placed into a higher orbit".

Comment: @Mołot I thought reputation applied to your space program, not individual pilots

Comment: @CyanAngel I'm not sure. And I don't like surprises. Last but not least - I have *fun* with letting different Kerbals visit moons ;)

Answer (score 4):

Kerbal Space Program always uses the first Kerbal on the astronaut list, it does not have the facility to remember your previous selection. You have to change the Kerbal every-time, or put Jeb in a permanent orbit to prevent him from returning to the KSC

Comment: I like to make a rocket and call it "Retirement" and launch Jeb, Bob and Bill into retirement